# How to update table from local database to webserver database

Tags: asp.net

I am developing Inventory software using asp.net 4.0  running through IIS from local machine.

In same thing i have upload on webserver, only for reportview. So i need to upload database or Update tables (stock,Payment) at end of everyday.

How to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create a windows service by using c# and schedule a job for that at the end of day.

Sample of windows service with scheduled job can be find in the below blog writing

http://www.techdoubts.net/2017/05/simple-job-scheduler-runs-repeatedly-once-day.html

Comment: Why is a windows service the best way? Why in C#? Whats wrong with SQL Agent or Windows Scheduler?

Comment: There is no wrong by using that services too. But by using a windows service, we do have full control of our code. If there is any structural difference between local and web server database, that is also handled.

Comment: If you write your replication in Perl and run it using windows scheduler.... you still have control over your code and can manage structural differences! Anyway there is many ways to do things and your suggestion is as valid as any other.

Comment: That is also a good idea. As you said many ways are available. I just suggested a way for his solution. I think there is no problem with my suggestion right? Also it can be manipulated in anyways too.

Comment: It certainly is a valid solution for the scheduling component but it doesn't actually have any content that deals with the question. Anyway I suspect the OP will just disappear anyway! Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database? You've tagged ASP.Net but that really doesn't have any relevance to your question.

If you are saying you want to duplicate your local database across to a different reporting-only database? There are many ways to do this.

A. Backup existing database, copy to remote database and restore

B. Used linked servers to transfer data

C. Use SSIS to transfer data

D. Set up a read only replica

E. Use powershell and SMO to script it

It probably comes down to whatever language you are comfortable with. If you are ASP.Net then that's probably C#. So you could follow up @Biby's answer and use this code to backup the database and restore it:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/873677/SQL-Server-Database-Backup-and-Restore-in-Csharp

You may or may not want to put that into a windows service. You also need to put a copy operation in there.

Do you have full access to your web reporting only server (i.e. can you set up SQL Agent jobs, copy files on to it, restore backups etc.)?

All four options can be automated. I'll try and find a link as this has been done and explained *many* times